# I use the command in (dir /b) batch files but it is throwing an error invalid syntax

Tags: python, windows, command

`os.system(r'cmd /c "for /f %a in ('dir /b "C:\Users\file\"') do ren "%a" "DRAWING_%a"")`

It was throwing an error at `dir /b` as invalid syntax.

Comment: os.system(r'cmd /c "for /f %a in ('dir /b "C:\Users\file\"') do ren "%a" "DRAWING_%a"")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I got solution and solution is

os.system(r'cmd /c "FOR /r "D:\BACKUPS\2018\" %a in (*) DO REN "%~a" "Drawing_%~nxa""')